# Grepping Port 22

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to grep output from an nmap scan by just parsing the greppable file output:

`cat $file | grep "22/open" | awk '{print $2}' > $results/service_ssh`

This works, however the fail is that any port with '22' in the last position is also added to the file, which is wrong (Ex. 8222/open, 8322/open, 1022/open, ...).

Should I be using something other than grep to do this?  I'm not the strongest at regex expressions yet, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That works @Biffen.  Want to make it the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`):

```
grep '\b22/open' "$file" | awk '{print $2}' > "$results/service_ssh"
```

---

<sup>There's [no need to use `cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat). And quoting variables is a good habit.</sup>

Comment: I learned somthing too today :) didn't know about \b yet. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
grep "^22/open" $file | awk '{print $2}' > $results/service_ssh
```

`^` matches the begin of the line.

or, if the line doesn't start with "22/open", you can use `\b` to mark the beginning of the word (as suggested by @Biffen).

```
grep "\b22/open" $file | awk '{print $2}' > $results/service_ssh
```

Comment: This won't work since the greppable output that nmap generates doesn't put `22/open` at the beginning of the line:  `Host: 10.10.10.106 (host) Ports: 22/open/tcp//ssh//OpenSSH 6.8 (protocol 2.0)/, 80/open/tcp//http?///, 111/open/tcp//rpcbind (rpcbind V2-4)/(rpcbind:100000*2-4)/2-4 (rpc #100000)/,`

Comment: I adapted my answer; you can use \b as suggested by @biffen in a comment